# setInterval to requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to convert the following setInterval() to requestAnimationFrame()?

Below is a simple working setInterval model that I'm using.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#add").click(function() {
         $('#result').html(
             (parseFloat($('#numA').val()) + 
              parseFloat($('#numB').val())).toString()
         );
    });
    setInterval(function () {$("#add").click()}, 1000);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nqqfq/4/

I've seen one that requires loop (game loop), but my code isn't about gaming. It's about parsing strings.

The documentation is a bit complicated. I've tried some trial-errors, but no success so far.

Thank you for any input.

Comment: Why are you doing this? Can't you just add keyup or change event to the inputs?

Comment: @elclanrs There are online interpreters similar to jsfiddle that auto-update. It's very cool that it inspired me to implement that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to invoke `requestAnimationFrame` repeatedly, for example:

```
!function frame() {
  $('#add').click()
  requestAnimationFrame(frame)
}()
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/nqqfq/6/

Comment: Yes, it's an IIFE, see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-this-iife-construct-in-javascript